# HDD not recognized correctly

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

MY 500gb HDD was working fine until a few reboots ago.

```
lsblk

NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   225G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0     8G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0 465.8G  0 part /media/usr/HDD1
sdc      8:32   0 465.8G  0 disk 
└─sdc1   8:33   0 465.8G  0 part 
sdd      8:48   0   1.8T  0 disk 
└─sdd1   8:49   0   1.8T  0 part /media/usr/My Passport
sde      8:64   0 465.8G  0 disk 
└─sde1   8:65   0 465.8G  0 part /media/usr/extHDD
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

sdc1 is the one I want.

However, trying to mount it with

```
sudo mount -t /dev/sdc1 /media/usr/HDD2
```

gives

```
mount: can't find /media/usr/HDD2 in /etc/fstab
```

so I run

```
blkid /dev/sdc1
```

which yields

```
/dev/sdc1: PARTUUID="0000814a-01"
```

sudo fdisk -l also gives no more information

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0000814a

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1          63 976771119 976771057 465.8G 83 Linux
```

[But it's definitely recognized by the system (link to screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDDaB.png)

So I'm lost.

edit 1:

```
ls /media/usr

HDD2 HDD1 My Passport extHDD
```

then

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab

# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name   #devices
#that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=da459b4f-512c-4fb6-926e-cdf082a9e2b6 /               ext4      errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=f9f8c1e3-3cbf-4979-b76a-c7af70186c9f none            swap    sw    0       0
```

edit 2

```
sudo fsck /dev/sdc1


fsck from util-linux 2.26.2
e2fsck 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdc1

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

Comment: Why `-t` ? Did you mean `-t ext4`

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you please give us a bit more information by [edit]ing your question and telling us: what's the output of `ls/media/usr`? What are the contents of `fstab`?  Please [edit] your question and add this information... (Please help us help you!) Then leave a comment @Fabby.

Comment: @RalphRönnquist I'm fairly new to ubuntu so i followed a guide. I've tried "-t ext4" but that gave me "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so."

Comment: Try without `-t`. I.e., `mount /dev/sdc1 /media/usr/HDD2`. If you really want to learn, try `man mount`.

Comment: @Fabby thank you for your help. I've edited the post with what i hope is sufficient

Comment: @RalphRönnquist same error again

Comment: please also add output of `sudo fsck /dev/sdc1`.

Comment: Looks like your disk is corrupt.  You might try using `testdisk` to recover if you haven't got a backup you can restore.

Comment: @RalphRönnquist done :)

Comment: @iwishiwasaneagle: As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of the answer, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it looks like the disk has got corrupt. If it was working before it may be possible to recover it, and possibly as @psusi suggests, running `testdisk` might do the job.

> sudo apt-get install testdisk

then

> sudo testdisk /dev/sdc1

I don't have a broken disk to test it on, and I don't know what it does to your, but it advertises itself as something that checks and recovers lost partitions, which sounds right, at least. Good luck.

Comment: Yes the disk was corrupted sadly. Tried to recover some data but it didn't work.  **Thank you for your help!**